# How to put text in the camera frame using 2 cameras?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I open 2 cameras in Python. I want to put text on one of cameras but it fails.

This is my program

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
   
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()
    if (ret0):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 1', frame1)
        cv2.putText(frame1, "halo" , (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2,(0, 255, 0), 2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: you put the `putText` after the `imshow`. you should have put it before the imshow. why do you expect the text to show up in the window after you've already shown the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work ! you put the `putText` after the `imshow`. you should have put it before the imshow.

```
import cv2 
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 
while True:

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()
    if (ret0):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.putText(frame1, "halo", (50, 50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Cam 1', frame1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: To improve this answer and to help other future readers (not just the OP), please provide an explanation of what you changed and how it solves the problem.